# pipe operator in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe

Sorry if this is a duplicate question :-)

I got below line of code from a batch script. (script.bat)

```
echo %DATE% %TIME% some text ... >> %logfile% | c:\path\script1.bat >> %logfile%
```

What is the significance of pipe (**|**) symbol here?

The script.bat is working fine from command line (script.bat), and it is running script1.bat as well.

While running script.bat from scheduled task it intermittently failed to run script1.bat, exiting with errorlevel 1.

Anyone have any idea what this **|** doing here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you know what pipes are normally used for. In your code, both sides of the pipe have their stdout redirected to a file. So the pipe is not fulfilling its normal purpose.

The way Windows implements pipes is to launch a new `cmd` thread for each side of the pipe.

In your case, the `|` is a quick and dirty way to instantiate parallel processing of the two commands.

**Update**

I just realized that both sides of the pipe are redirecting stdout to the same log file. That should never work, because only one `cmd` process (or thread) at a time can have the file open for write access. It certainly does not work for me from the command line. I get the following error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` The only way that does not fail is if `logfile` is set to `nul`.

If I had to guess, I think the original developer intended to use `&` instead of `|`. There is no reason to run a single ECHO statement in parallel with another batch script. It looks like the first statement is simply a timestamp.

I think your code should look like

```
echo %DATE% %TIME% some text ... >> %logfile% & call c:\path\script1.bat >> %logfile%
```

or better yet

```
>>%logfile% (
  echo %DATE% %TIME% some text ...
  call c:\path\script1.bat
)
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, as per my understanding this pipe have no role (is ugly) here, as first command output is redirected to logfile. (This code is not written by me)
If I run script.bat from command prompt, it is successful every time (up to my knowledge).
The script.bat usually run from scheduled task, and its failed to run script1.bat intermittently, errorlevel is 1.
If it’s a syntax error then it should show only one behavior, this makes me wonder.
As I am not a master :-) in batch scripting, I was thinking it is some advanced usage of pipe.but I can’t find any documentation for this :-(

Comment: @Opera - I've updated the answer to show what I think the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: waaw , thats right, "only one cmd process (or thread) at a time can have the file open for write access". I think this will fix my issue. I will test it and will come back with the result tomorrow. thank you very much :-) :-)